# Measuring Subjective Beliefs

Tags: reference-request, decision-theory, experimental-economics

I am starting on a research project that requires the measurement of subjective beliefs of subjects around uncertainty. Since I'm new in this field I'm looking for references that can help me get started. In this project we can survey the subjects but bringing them to lab might not be possible. I'll appreciate any leads in this direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have half a dozen [questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/5863/sher-afghan?tab=questions) with upvoted answers. Please consider accepting some of these.

Answer (score 3):

you can do a belief elicitation.
See more on this here:

- Rauhut, H., 2013. Beliefs about lying and spreading of dishonesty: Undetected lies and their constructive and destructive social dynamics in dice experiments. *PloS one*, 8(11), p.e77878.

and here:

- Gächter, S. and Renner, E., 2010. The effects of (incentivized) belief elicitation in public goods experiments. *Experimental Economics, 13(3)*, pp.364-377.

If you don't want to invite them into the lab, you can use Amazon mTurk and oTree.